# Why do LEDs have only RGB (Red, Green, Blue) colors?

Tags: light-emitting-diodes

After some studies I've found LEDs having 3 colors RGB (Red, Green and Blue), I was very interested in this topic so this question is up. The Diagram will tell the colors in LEDs.[image: Red,Green and Blue color in LEDs]

```
> Red, Green and Blue color in LEDs
```

> Why only RGB is needed?
>
> Why can't any other color be replaced?
>
> Why MCY Cannot be used?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Thank you @Qmechanic! It's already from Photograph.SE. I am tired of it!

Comment: You can buy LEDs and laser diodes with many different wavelengths for different applications. For common electronics, the RGB selection is quite common for display and indicator applications. So, manufacturers have made all-in-one RGB devices. That is all.

Comment: Crossposted from https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85538

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about user- & vision-preferences rather than physics.

Comment: I'd certainly vote to reopen if this question were put along the lines of: "Can LEDs emit in colors other than RGB? What is the physics that sets an LED's color and what are the limitations to color set by this physics?

Comment: Re, "Why only RGB needed?"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#Physiology_of_color_perception

Comment: Re, "Why MCY can not be used?"  Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow are the so-called "subtractive" primaries.  In printing, you control the amount of red, green, and blue light that are reflected off the paper by layering/mixing transparent inks that absorb the colors that you _don't_ want reflected;  Cyan ink absorbs red light, magenta ink absorbs green light, and yellow ink absorbs blue light.  Usually, there is a fourth black ink, (the four color process is known as CMYK) because the C, M, and Y dyes are not perfect, and do not yield a satisfying black when all are mixed together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, LEDs of other colours do exist, like, for example yelow. I think that the only reason for the usage of RGB is that those 3 are the light primary colors. That's not a minor reason, since we the humans have only three types of cones (of those colors), and so they alone can generate any other oen we can actually see.

What's more, there are led's emmiting in infrarred, as in your remote control. People, please correct me if I'm wrong.